# Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  I have a problem that nautilus is suddenly crashing and I still don't know why this is happening.

```
ExecutablePath
  /user/bin/nautilus

Package
  nautilus 1:3.26.4-0-ubuntu18.04.5

Problem Type
  Crash

Title
  nautilus crashed with SIGSEGV in nautilus_file_invalidate_attributes_internal()

ApportVersion
  2.20.9-ubuntu7.14

Architecture
  amd64

CurrentDesktop
  ubuntu:GNOME

DistroRelease
  Ubuntu 18.04

GsettingsChanges
  b'org.gnome.nautilus.window-state' b'sidebar-width' b253'

InstallationMedia
  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS "Bionic Beaver" - Release amd64 (20200203.1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? Can you elaborate on what is happening (or not happening)?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug in Ubuntu 18.04.
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/954409

No remedy, though.